# What is best practice to delete dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, heap-memory, delete-operator

I have to reassign `iScreen` and `oScreen` many times with `new` keyword.

I found that I have to `delete` them every single time before reassign new heap memory.

It seems like bad practice to me. Is there any better way to solve this code repetition?

```
Matrix* oScreen;
Matrix* iScreen;

iScreen = new Matrix(100, 100);
oScreen = new Matrix(100, 100);

//do something with iScreen, oScreen

delete iScreen; // have to write same "delete iScreen" every single time?
iScreen = new Matrix(150, 150);
delete oScreen;
oScreen = new Matrix(150, 150);
```

Comment: In my opinion, best practice is to hold all dynamically allocated objects in an owning container of some sort.  Primarily `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Take a step back. Why do you have to reassign `iScreen` and `oScreen` many times with `new` keyword?

Comment: Do you really need re-allocation `*iScreen = Matrix(150, 150);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider holding your dynamic objects in a container like [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you can. Otherwise, they should be managed by a *smart pointer* like [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

```
std::unique_ptr<Matrix> iScreen;

iScreen = std::make_unique<Matrix>(100, 100);

// do something with iScreen

iScreen = std::make_unique<Matrix>(150, 150); // no need to delete
```

You don't have to delete the old one, the *smart pointer* does that automaticaly when you assign a new one.